# How to follow next pages in Scrapy Crawler to scrape content

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I am able to scrape all the stories from the first page,my problem is how to move to the next page and continue scraping stories and name,kindly check my code below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from cancerstories.items import CancerstoriesItem
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    story = scrapy.Field()
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'cancerstories'
    allowed_domains = ['thebreastcancersite.greatergood.com']
    start_urls = ['http://thebreastcancersite.greatergood.com/clickToGive/bcs/stories/']

    def parse(self, response):

        rows = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"story")]')

        #loop over all links to stories
        for row in rows:
            myItem = MyItem() # Create a new item
            myItem['name'] = row.xpath('./text()').extract() # assign name from link
            story_url = response.urljoin(row.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]) # extract url from link
            request = scrapy.Request(url = story_url, callback = self.parse_detail) # create request for detail page with story
            request.meta['myItem'] = myItem # pass the item with the request
            yield request

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        myItem = response.meta['myItem'] # extract the item (with the name) from the response
        #myItem['name']=response.xpath('//h1[@class="headline"]/text()').extract()
        text_raw = response.xpath('//div[@class="photoStoryBox"]/div/p/text()').extract() # extract the story (text)
        myItem['story'] = ' '.join(map(unicode.strip, text_raw)) # clean up the text and assign to item
        yield myItem # return the item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your `scrapy.Spider` for a [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider), and use `Rule` and `LinkExtractor` to follow the link to the next page.

For this approach you have to include the code below:

```
...
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
...
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='\.\./stories;jsessionid=[0-9A-Z]+?page=[0-9]+')),
)
...
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
...
```

This way, for each page you visit the spider will create a request for the next page (if present), follow it when finishes the execution for the parse method, and repeat the process again.

**EDIT:**

The rule I wrote is just to follow the next page link not to extract the stories, if your first approach works it's not necessary to change it.

Also, regarding the rule in your comment, `SgmlLinkExtractor` is deprecated so I recommend you to use the default [link extractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=linkextractor#link-extractors), and the rule itself is not well defined.

When the parameter `attrs` in the extractor is not defined, it searchs links looking for the `href` tags in the body, which in this case looks like `../story/mother-of-4435` and not `/clickToGive/bcs/story/mother-of-4435`. That's the reason it doesn't find any link to follow.

Comment: Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/clickToGive\/bcs\/stories\?\page\=[0-9]+'), ), callback="parseme", follow= True), adding this doesnt crawl even the first page

Comment: I edit the answer to write a proper reply to the comment, I hope it helps

Comment: yes thanks, the linkextractor can now follow the links, but it seems it continuously scraps the pages to the end and then follows the prev link again to the beginning

Comment: That behaviour responds to the Scrapy architecture underlying the spider. Your are trying to follow the execution as written in the spider but the data flow is a bit more complicated. I recommend you to read on this page, it helps to understand the process: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html

Comment: I managed to get all the contents correctly, thanks so much for your help @javitronxo

Answer (score 0):

you can follow next pages manually if you would use scrapy.spider class,example:
next_page = response.css('a.pageLink  ::attr(href)').extract_first()
if next_page:
       absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
       yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
Do not forget to rename your parse method to parse_start_url if you want to use CralwSpider class